# Menu not working on iOS via Cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, html, css, cordova

I'm currently working on a hybrid mobile app and after i changed my code for the new menu, I got some problems for iOS.

[image]

[image]

So here it's simple, on the emulator everything is fine, but on iOS, the menu is grey like the right side and when I press something on the menu, it close it directly !

I don't understand why it doesn't work because I don't have any problems on Android.

My code is simple :

```
<div id="menu" class="touch-menu-la">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title" style="background-color: #1A237E">
            <img class="logoMenu alignCenterImg" src="../img/logo.png">
        </span>
        <ul class="menu-items">
            <li>
                <a href="events.html">
                    <img src="../img/icons/events.png" class="imgMenuList"></img>Événements
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="happyHours.html">
                    <img src="../img/icons/happyHours.png" class="imgMenuList"></img>Happy Hours
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="bonsPlans.html">
                    <img src="../img/icons/bonPlan.png" class="imgMenuList"></img>Bons Plans
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="cocktails.html">
                    <img src="../img/icons/cocktails.png" class="imgMenuList"></img>Cocktails
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="games.html">
                    <img src="../img/icons/jeux.png" class="imgMenuList"></img>Jeux
                </a>
            </li>
            <div class="tonight-drawer-separator"></div>
            <li>
                <a href="about.html">
                    <img src="../img/icons/info.png" class="imgMenuList"></img>À propos
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  <script>
    var TouchMenu = TouchMenuLA({
        target: document.getElementById('menu')
    });

    document.getElementById('menu-open').addEventListener('click', function(){
        TouchMenu.toggle();
    });
</script>
```

Does someone got any idea ?

I'm really lost with this problem.

Thank's

Comment: Its very difficult to understand your question please put the screenshot of the problem too!

Comment: This seems like it is probably an iphone build settings problem. I had something similar a few weeks ago.

Comment: @Stacklearner : Oops, I forgot the screenshot of the Iphone, here you're ;) 
Travis : How did you manage to correct it ?

Comment: @TravisTubbs How did you manage to correct it ?